# Symfony2 error Looked for namespace "services", found none

Tags: php, symfony

i have an error starting with Symfony2.

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 356:
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "services" (in /Users/jm/Documents/Websites/www.brsymfony.dev/src/CalcBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/services.yml). Looked for namespace "services", found none

My services.yml look like and it has whitespaces correctly:

```
services:
    Calculator:
        class: CalcBundle\Services\Calculator
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    ListOperations:
        class: CalcBundle\Services\ListOperations
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
```

Can anyone help me?

--

Yes, i have this code on CalcExtension.php inside DependencyInjection folder:

```
<?php

namespace CalcBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * Class AppExtension
 */

class CalcExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * Loads a specific configuration.
     *
     * @param array            $config    An array of configuration values
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container A ContainerBuilder instance
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When provided tag is not defined in this extension
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function load(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the extension on the DependencyInjection folder? Should be CalcBundle/DependencyInjection/CalcExtension.php

You have the documentation with examples here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

The services.yml should be located on CalcBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

Be careful because examples are creating parameters and services together into config.yml, you have to adapt it to your case (services.yml and parameters.yml separated, I would recommend your way)

You have the documentation with examples here

https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: Can you put it here please?